# Disable UIView on TouchesMoved

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, touchesmoved

I have an application in which i have to move images, problem is arising when mouse touches the images it gets moved but if it touches the main View, whole view is also moving.

I tried view.userInteractionEnabled=NO;

but after one move whole view gets freeze.

I want my view to be static(not moving)

Help !!!

here is the code

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {  
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

    UIImageView *imgPimples = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    imgPimples = (UIImageView*)[touch view];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:imgPimples];
    imgPimples.center = touchLocation;
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
}
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
}
```

Comment: can you post your `touchesEnded` `touchesMoved` and `touchesBegan` code??

Comment: you really don't want to be doing an alloc in touchesMoved, especially if you're not releasing it!

Comment: actually I am adding the same image on every click of button, thats y i nee to alloc ( i think) m a beginner so donno deep about it .

Comment: then create the button once in touches began, not every time the touch moves. at present you're creating lots of images on one touch if the touch moves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check whether touched class is of kind UIImageView.

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    if ([[touch view] isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
        UIImageView *imgPimple;
        imgPimple = (UIImageView *)[touch view]; 
        CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:imgPimple];
        imgPimple.center = touchLocation;
    }
```

}

I think it will serve your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]){
imgPimples.center = touchLocation;
}
```

assuming your parent view is not also a UIImageView.